# How to retrieve a list of record including only one child each?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, domain-driven-design

**Sample models.**

```
public class Root
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; private set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string RootId { get; private set; }
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

**Constraints.**

Child has the **RootId** and **Code** property as its unique key. This means that each Root object is only allowed to have as many Child objects as long as no two or more Child contains the same code.

**Sample query**

*Get all Root records with Child that have Code equals A100.*

**Sample List Data Containing two Root objects**

```
Root1 with 2 children, one having a code A100 and the other A200.

Root2 with 2 children, one having a code A100 and the other A500.
```

The current query that I am doing right now is get all the Root records first along with all their children. Then, iterate each of the records and remove all of its children that doesn't have the same code that I am querying. The problem with this approach is when the database grows, it will have an impact on this method since I am retrieving all children when all I need is one for each Root objects.

**Sample code**

```
var records = context.Roots
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Code == "A100"))
    .ToList();

foreach (var root in records)
{
    foreach (var child in root.Children)
    {
        if (!child.Code == "A100")
        {
            root.Children.Remove(child);
        }
    }
}
```

My models have their property setters set to private following DDD principles. So I cannot do linq projections using the **Select()** command like the following.

```
var records = context.Roots
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Code == "A100"))
    .Select(x => new Root{...})
    .ToList();
```

Using the constructor is also not ideal in my case because I am setting the state of each object to **Created** during instantation as part of the design of each model.

**Edit 1**

I could use the constructor in the LINQ projection using Select() but my problem is, in all of my models, there is a property called **State** where I update in various points in my model depending on what occurred. In the constructor part, I update it to a **Create** state to imply the fact the a new model was created. So if I am going to create a constructor just so I could create an instance of the model from the database, that would lead to confusion because I am just retrieving an already existing record from the database and if I am going to use the constructor, the code, during the instantiation will mark the model as **Created** which is not what I want because it will create a new meaning in my design.

**Edit 2**

My apologies for not making myself clear enough. My problem is on this part of the query.

Part 1.

```
var records = context.Roots
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Code == "A100"))
    .ToList();
```

So I won't need to arrive on this part.

Part 2

```
foreach (var root in records)
{
    foreach (var child in root.Children)
    {
        if (!child.Code == "A100")
        {
            root.Children.Remove(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Now based on the constraints I mentioned.

**Constraint 1. Not using public setters, so I cannot use this.**

```
var records = context.Roots
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Code == "A100"))
    .Select(x => new Root{...})
    .ToList();
```

**Constaint 2. Not using constructor**

```
var records = context.Roots
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Code == "A100"))
    .Select(x => new Root(...))
    .ToList();
```

The bottom line is, is there a query that I can use or any other method get the records I want, straight from the database without doing the second part of the query?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are *removing* all non-A100 nodes *from the original list data* with your sample code. If this is not your intention and you actually want a copy, you need a way to construct or copy at least your root items, which makes the solution a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I am removing all non-A100 nodes from the list retrieved from the database because all children records are fetched using this command Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Code == "A100")). I am trying to figure out how to get just one child record instead of retrieving all of them based on constraints I mentioned above.

Comment: With your code you remove the non-A100 children from your original data, not only from the result. You fetch references with your LINQ statement, put the references in a list, run through all those references and actually remove the children not only from the result, but from your original data, since you never made a copy of a root item or a child. In `context` only root items with no A100 or with a single A100 child are left.

Comment: Try this query so you dont need to remove child  manually => `var result = (from root in context.Roots.Include(x => x.Children)
                          from child in root.Children
                          where child.Code == "A100"
                          select root).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, your answer is different than my comment check once. I provide OP as traditional linq and I didnt find ant linq code in your answer

Comment: So finally it will be => `var result = (from root in context.Roots.Include(x => x.Children)
                          from child in root.Children
                          where child.Code == "A100"
                          select root).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @devpro101, try the code in above comment and let me know :)

Comment: @er-sho Deleted my comment tho' since you edited yours... back and forth ;-)

Comment: @kaedinger, finally I tested it works on `x.Children` so updated

Comment: @er-sho thank you for your suggestion, it worked but I need the child data as well not just the root. I am expecting to get a list or roots (denoted by .ToList() in my query above) and at the same time each of the root object in the list should have at most one child object.

Comment: What if you flatten your query result to anonymous object in `select` clause?

Comment: Not possible I think because I need an instance of type Root, so I need to convert it back to its type...

Comment: So how can you get an instance of type root because you setter is private you can't make any new root object from query result

Comment: @er-sho that's what I've been telling him since my first comment, and my hour old solution takes account of that. I hope he sometimes gets around looking at it.

Comment: You are putting too many constraints to entity model, which is supposed to be a [logical data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_schema). In general mixing [domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) with LDM is not a good idea - LDM must not have all these constraints (private setters, get/set behaviors, constructor logic etc.). Better create separate models and map between the two where needed. Anyway, what EF are you using (EF6, EF Core (version?))? Depending on that there could be a solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Hey I figured it out, I was mistaken, you are right I could use anonymous types. Please put in your answer to the answers section so I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you so much @er-sho

Comment: @devpro101, I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try traditional LINQ so you will not more need to remove children manually and project your query result to the anonymous object.

```
var result = (from root in context.Roots.Include(x => x.Children)
          from child in root.Children
          where child.Code == "A100"
          select new
          {
              Id = root.Id,
              Children = child
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice one. Worth mentioning though that this still checks all children of a root item.

Comment: @kaedinger, Yes to apply a specific filter like `A100` on a collection its need to check by using `where` clause and its return if exist

Comment: @ er-sho, Of course, unless you check it manually (see my solution) or use `FirstOrDefault`, where you need to apply additional filtering. Also,  `Children` in your solution is not a Collection. But since the OP changed his premises several times, I guess that doesn't matter.

Comment: @kaedinger, yes OP only want only one unique child per root object so no need to return `Collection`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some kind of sorting in your data storage that you can use you still have to "retrieve" items to look at them. And if you want a *copy* of your data with the result instead of modifying your *context* data, you need some kind of cloning. So in my opinion - considering your constraints - it is best to only keep references on the resulting `Root`and `Child` items:

```
var l = new List<Tuple<Root, Child>>();
foreach(var p in context.Roots.Include(x => x.Children))
{
    foreach(var c in p.Children)
    {
        if(c.Code == "A100")
        {
            l.Add(Tuple.Create(p, c));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you only look at the children and the root items once, and only check children until you found your item. The resulting list of tuples contain references to your respective `Root` and `Child` items without modifying them, so don't use the `Children` property of your referenced `Root` items.